# Calling WCF service from a remote javascript

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf

I have a WCF service (XML+JSON) running on http://servicehost:8080/myService. 
My ASP.NET application with jQuery is running on http://webapp/Login.aspx

I want jQuery to use Ajax and call the URL http://servicehost:8080/myService. The browser does not allow this cross-host call, which is expected. 
Some of the posts on stackoverflow suggested using JSONP. Is that the only option?

Is there a way to define a proxy service on the http://webapp and have it access the remote WCF service?

Thanks

Abhi

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to define a proxy
>   service on the http://webapp and have
>   it access the remote WCF service?

Yes, and that's what I'd do. There are a lot of ways to do it.  If you use a load-balancer or other front-end proxy software, you could route there.  Also, you could proxy with IIS proxy server

http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/8322/extending-iis-with-proxy-server.html

There are third-party and open-source alternatives (e.g. Apache could be just your proxy)

Probably, you'd want to do something like that anyway -- not everyone can open up port 8080 (like inside of corporate firewalls).